# create angular user list (efficiently )

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, mongodb, express

i wanted to create user list like this image given below 
[image]

i use angular and bootstrap for the basic's , my problem is , what if the users is more then 10k , what would be the efficient way to call recent user and how to handle the pagination and how to filter within huge number of user , if i call 10k long john i think it will be very heavy .

Here is my code to call users

```
$http.get('/users').success(function (data) {
        $scope.users = data.results;
        alert(data);
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        alert(status);
    });
```

I use mongodb and express.js

Comment: On the hand of your "question". Could you possibly come up with something more broad than 1. Show list of users from data I am not showing. 2. Not even showing how your service side is actually fetching the data ( seems to be most of the point of the question ), 3. Since you include an "image" then I suppose you have no template layout to display this, so should we code all you markup and CSS as well?. Too broad.

Comment: i do have all the html css done , you can also check it out codeply.com/go/phIHFKawJG

Comment: Could you comply with the CC license of the `randomuser.me` and 1000 faces dataset you are using for your demo and provide attribution? Yes, the photos and random user data are very liberally licensed, but that license does require you attribute the authors.

Comment: i removed the images now

Comment: may be angular-vs-repeat is suitable for this kind of task, since its only render what certain amount on screen - http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/#?tab=8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the user information by the code you have pasted here. I think the "results" variable doesn't mean anything. If it's true, please fix the code like this way:

```
$http.get('/users').success(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data;
    alert(data);
    }).error(function (data, status) {
    alert(status);
});
```

If you want to get the recent value, you can use code like this in your controller code:

```
User.find({}).sort({
    'datetime': -1
}).limit(20);
```

This code will return last 20 users.

Courtesy to Andrew Mata, this code might work in your case:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items|limitTo:20">{{item}}</div>
```

But this will initially load the whole dataset returned from "/users" API call.

Comment: it will return 20 users thats ok , but what if i wanted to search from my entire user list ?

Answer (score 3):

Angular allows you to iterate over an array of items such that it does not immediately load everything at one time. The following should suffice.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items|limitTo:4">{{item}}</div>
```